# Godot SQLite Database on Android Export

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, godot, gdscript

I have a questions when I export my project to Android.

I have the following files and folders in my `res://`

```
res://addons/godot-sqlite/
res://dataStore/database.db
res://dataStore/database.sqbpro
res://globalenv/globalfunctions.gd
res://globalenv/globalvar.gd
res://scenes/
```

I have some issues with exporting my local db in the Android export, for example, I have in my code the following variables:

```
const SQLite = preload("res://addons/godot-sqlite/bin/gdsqlite.gdns")
var db # database object
var db_name = "res://dataStore/database.db" # database path
```

I've changed the path of the database.db to

```
var db_name = "user://database.db"
```

A then I copied the database.db to my

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Godot\app_userdata\project-name
```

In the Godot "Play the project" button the database is working fine but when I export the project to Android adding the `database.db` to the non-resources filter in resources and the `.apk` is installed the login is not working.

[filter to export non-resources files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bik2h.png)

any ideas?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the export with a wildcard, e.g. `*.db`. *There is an issue - which I believe still stands - that this option does not work if it does not have a wildcard.*

That should make the `*.db` files available in their `res://` path. Which is read only.

Since read only is not good for a database, copy it to the `user://` path. You can use an object of the [`Directory`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_directory.html) class to check if it already exists, and to copy from `res://` to `user://` if it doesn't.

Then proceed to work with the database from the `user://` path.

Comment: I copied the database.db to the `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Godot\app_userdata\project-name` and added the *.db to the export but it still does not read the database.
What am I missing?

Comment: I should copy all of the Godot SQLite addons to the user:// path too?

Comment: @gabe "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Godot\app_userdata\project-name" is in your PC, isn't? - Don't you want it Android? I'm not telling you to copy the database to the user path of your PC manually. I'm telling you to write code to copy the database from the res path to the user path of the Android using the Directory class.

Comment: I understand now. I made the following code in the first scene on the `_ready` function:
`var dir = Directory.new()`
`dir.copy("res://dataStore/database.db", "user://")`

And the database.db and the file appeared but in a folder named "files" (I'm using Android Studio to debug)

How wrong am I with my code?

Comment: Nevermind, I just missing the `"user://database.db"` in the second argument of the copy function.
THANK YOU for your help, you are my hero now! lol Love you<3